# Formatting date using day.dart turns hour 12 into 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the library day.dart (https://github.com/dayjs/day.dart/blob/master/API.md#format-format) to format dates in a flutter/dart app and when I call format with the format being 'h:mm A', it return something like 0:00 AM whereas I'd like 12:00 AM.

Based on the docs, it looks like it should return 12:00 AM. Am I missing something? Is this a bug with the library? And if anyone has any recommendations on using Day.dart vs. just DateTime I'm open to any suggestions!

Comment: The Flutter DateTime library is enough for basic DateTime operations
https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html
For advanced DateTime formatting you may use, https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Answer (score 0):

Use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package in dart

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(final List<String> args) {
  print(
      DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.parse("2000-10-31T00:00:00.000")));
}
```

Output:

```
12:00 AM
```